# Node js difference b/w directly calling a function (using module.export) and using prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, prototype

**First approach using module.export without creating object**

File:AuthFilter.js

```
function callbackAuthService() {  
....AUTH SERVICE CALLBACK CODE....  
}  

module.exports = {  
    checkAuthentication: function() {  
.....HTTP REQ TO AUTH SERVICE......  
}
```

File app.js(using checkAuthentication)

```
var authFilter = require('./filters/AuthFilter');  

/* Before Filter */  
app.all('*', authFilter.checkAuthentication);
```

**Second approach using prototype by creating object**

File:AuthFilter.js

```
var authFilter = function()
{

function callbackAuthService() {  
....AUTH SERVICE CALLBACK CODE....  
}  

this.checkAuthentication=function() {  
.....HTTP REQ TO AUTH SERVICE......  
}
}
module.exports = authFilter;
```

File app.js(using checkAuthentication)

```
var authFilter = require('./filters/AuthFilter');  
var authFilterObj=new(authFilter);

/* Before Filter */  
app.all('*', authFilterObj.checkAuthentication);
```

Which way is better ?
as far as i know in node js functions are object so in first way we are exporting function object and calling it (it is not static function call).
Please correct if i am wrong (please consider design style and performance in mind).
Also while using lib like sha1,mongo,redis,sql,request i observed that i don't have to create the object and the use their functions(means they are using first approach)